# How to detect Disk drive letter using batch code

Tags: batch-file

I need help from you guys. I want to create a batch file that will detect running DVD in disk Drive and after that, I want the batch file to write it's letter into a text file.
Now can you help me with wiritng the batch code that will do so?
I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2):

This will list all drive letters in `drives.txt`:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (if exist "%%~a:" Echo %%~a: >> drives.txt)
```

Which produced for me:

```
C:
P:
R:
S:
```

Comment: I think he meant the detection of a letter of available/active comact disk (DVD).

Comment: Yes , I want the detection  of a letter of disk.But I want batch file to detect letter of disk ,When the DVD/CD running in it.Any help please

Answer (score 0):

This will detect the letter of your DVDR/Disk drive and echo it to the file DISK.TXT

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (
  if [%%j]==[5] echo %%i>Disk.txt
  )
endlocal
```